# Artifactory backup directory is not recognized

Tags: artifactory

I wanted to change the backup to a different disk. I mounted the disk to `/mnt2` on centos and when I navigate to Admin > Backups > Backup Daily > Edit backup-daily Backup, I see an option **Server Path For Backup**. I tried the following two things.

1. I entered the mount directory `/mnt2` and hit run now. The background job fails with the following error in logs.

> An error occurred while performing a backup: Backup directory provided
>   in configuration: '/mnt2' cannot be created or is not a directory.

2. I also tried creating a `tmp2` directory on local drive and entered `/tmp2` and hit run now. The background job fails with the same error as above.

Note 1:
I restarted the docker container just to see if it's not picking up file system changes in real time. That did not work.

Note 2:
There is a browse button next to Sever Path for Backup and I dont see `/mnt2` or `/tmp2` directories I created. I couldnot find anything useful in the documentation either.

How do I change the backup directory for artifactory?

Comment: Check the permissions on the mounted directory. The user running Artifactory shall have write permission to the selected directory.

Comment: Hey @gba Thanks for the comment.

I would like to close this request. Instead of creating directory under docker volume home directory, I created it under / . I would like to somehow close this with relevant comment or tag, if possible.

Comment: You might just add an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The setup is artifactory with docker.

For artifactory docker instance, a volume needs to be specified so it maps to the local folder, say, `/opt/artifactory/`.
In my case, `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory`(docker) is mapped to `/opt/artifactory`(local)

I am supposed to create a folder here -- `/opt/artifactory/backup_mount`. Give read and write access for 1039 user and group. It shows up in artifactory UI as `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/backup_mount`.

Note:

- If you create a directory, it shows up without any docker restart.
- If you create a mount, restart docker so the mount is recognized.